# Efficient way of truncating a trace file when it gets too big?

Tags: asp.net, trace

I'm using .NET's built-in Tracing mechanism to trace program execution.  The problem is the trace file can grow to several MB very quickly.  Is there an efficient way of truncating the file when it grows past a certain point?  I thought of putting in a check whenever something gets written (I have a custom class that inherits from TraceListener) but that might degrade performance too much.  Maybe a Timer would be a better solution?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement a custom trace listener:

> Let's see how we can solve fairly common task: managing continuously generated trace files. Default trace listener implementation is not really suitable for service applications that are supposed to be always active. If application produces a lot of trace output, then sooner or later this information will use up all disk space.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/customnettracelisteners.aspx?display=Print

With this example, you are able to create log chunck like this:

```
MyTrace.txt (recent trace information); 
MyTrace00.txt (trace history backup); 
MyTrace01.txt (trace history backup); 
and so on...
```

Of course, you can throw backup files away.

(Just a hint: try *log4net* ([here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net)) and *Enterprise Library Logging Block* ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309506.aspx))!)

Comment: The reason I'm using the built-in tracing is because I don't need big logging solution.  I just need to be able to trace during debugging sessions

Comment: I think you are mistaken, ilitirit - you say you don't need a big logging solution, but you want to customise how things are stored.  So you do need a big logging solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use an Event Log trace listener, since the EventLog can be easily automatically cycled in this way.

Comment: I already log information to the Event log, but it doesn't contain Trace Information.  I only enable tracing during Debug or QA sessions.